# Drawing diagrams on HTML?

Tags: html, drawing, diagramming

I need to prepare a **HTML page** on which people can **draw** UML, network, bpmn, etc. **diagrams**. I made a research if **MS Visio** can be used this way with a plug-in, but I couldn' t find any information. We also need to create our **own stencil** which is possible in Visio. I think people use **Dojo** like js libraries to achieve this, but I want to ask for your suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot use HTML5 (Canvas and SVG), then you probably need to revert to one of the good old plugin based solutions. A very mature and performant platform is Silverlight, although people tend to call it deprecated in favor of HTML5 - the same holds true for Flash (Flex) based solutions, and of course the good old Java applets. For all of these platforms there are open source and also commercially backed closed-source solutions available:

http://www.google.com/search?q=silverlight+diagramming+control

http://www.google.com/search?q=flex+diagramming+library

http://www.google.com/search?q=java+diagramming+library

Answer (score 2):

you can use html5 to achieve this. just google "*html5 canvas drawing*"

you will see a lot of samples

Comment: HTML5 is not supported by our company' s default browsers yet. Any other ideas?

Comment: You may also use Pencil. It can be used as Firefox plugin.
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/pencil/